# How do I update (and keep it up to date) a old react.js project?

Tags: reactjs, build-dependencies

I have an old react project I am trying to get back into. Its been a few months since and I know there is updates for it. I tried to update them as I read on the internet how, but now my project isn't working. Some of the dependencies are out of date, it says there are vulnerabilities. Is there a way to fix it? and Is there a easy way to check other than going to each dependency? Is there a way to automate it so I dont have to remember? Any tips on how to manage a react project would be great as I am still a student and learning. Thanks

I tried to update the version in my package.json files.  I also tried to delete my node_modules folder after everything broke. It broke it worse.

Comment: The project must be under version control first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the best way to handle dependencies is to upgrade them one-by-one, fixing problems as you go. I would start over by removing your `node_modules`, then reinstall your old node_modules using your lock file:

**npm**

npm ci

**yarn**

yarn install --frozen-lockfile

This way your old dependencies are installed as they were. Your app should be in a working state. Now go through your dependencies from the top-down to uninstall then reinstall each one. This allows you to fix any issues as you go, instead of trying to upgrade all packages at once and drowning in errors.

There's no automated way to handle breaking changes in external libraries.